# Regular Expression alternatives in Visual Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a Regular Expression like : `.Resolve<I[a-zA-Z]*Repository>`
I'm using this RegExp in Viusal Studio to find the desired repositories like:

```
unity.Resolve<ISomeRepositry>();
```

[image]

Is there any alternative way to find the wished repositories in VS or this is the only way to do that?

Comment: What is dissatisfying about the way you have found? What do the other repositories look like?

Comment: I need to remove all repostiories like ISomeRepositry and resolved; we have to created with unit of work.

Comment: All repositories shall begin with I and ending with Repository this is the pattern. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which Visual Studio Version?

Comment: black and white and ugly as in the image :) so 2012; I think no way I have to use RegExp or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to escape the spacial characters in the regex, any of the following needs to be escaped: `<>[]{}().` among others.

So this should work:

```
unity\.Resolve\<I[a-zA-Z0-9]+\>\(\);
```

Alternatively you could of course use the Find All References feature in Visual Studio to find all occurrences of each Repository.

Comment: (Tested in VS2013, older versions of Visual Studio use a slightly different regex engine, which is why I asked which version you're using).

Comment: it is still RegExp but it find all what i need like IWaste9Repostiory etc. Thanks it is works better!